# Is there a way to exclude rows and columns in a C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, rcpp

Suppose I have an array in C++ such as the following:

```
1  2  3  4 = arr
5  6  7  8
9  9  8  9
7  6  1  3
```

Is there a concise way to exclude any row and/or column?

For example, suppose I want to do an operation on the following array:

```
1  3  4
5  7  8
7  1  3
```

In other programming languages, I can obtain the above array fairly easy with arr[-3,-2] to exclude the third row and second column. However, I have been unable to find a concise way to exclude rows and columns in C++. How would you go about it?

**Update:**

I suppose this is an XY problem. Let me tell you why I want to do this.

I am running a statistical model, specifically a conditional autoregressive (CAR) model. In this Gaussian model, we need the mean function and covariance matrix.

We obtain the mean function as

mean = mu + Sig(i,-i) * inv(Sig(-i,-i)) * (**v**(i,-i) - mu)

and the covariance matrix as

s2 = Sig(i,i) - Sig(i,-i) * inv(Sig(-i,-i)) * Sig(-i,i)

So, I need to obtain three variants of the matrix Sig: Sig(l,-l), Sig(-l,-l), Sig(-l,l). This is why I'm hoping to find a simple way to exclude rows and columns. I would usually program this in R, but it's taking so long. So, I'm hoping to get it working in Rcpp.

**Next Update:**

I think I'm figuring it out, so thank you to the commenters. This is what I'm thinking. I need a vector that stores the indices that I want to keep in my submatrix. I plan on using Rcpp's X.submat() function.

Suppose the I want to obtain the submatrix of Sig that excludes the ith row and ith column. Then I must have a vector of indices that contains {0,1,...,(i-2),i,...,(L-1)}, since C++ indexing starts at 0. To obtain this vector of indices, I have the following code:

```
// We need to get the vector of indices excluding i
  arma::vec vece = arma::zeros(L-1); // vector to exclude the ith index
  for(int k = 0; k < (L-1); k++){ // we have a vector of length L-1
    if(k < (i-1)){
      vece(k)=k;
    }
    else if(k == (i-1)){
      // do not add the ith index
    }
    else{ // k > (i-1)
      vece(k-1) = k;
    }
  }
  
  // We need to make Sig(-i,-i)
  arma::mat Sigee = arma::zeros(L-1,L-1); // ee for exclude,exclude
  Sigee = Sig.submat(vece,vece)
```

However, this does not appear to work when i = 0. I have this code within the following for-loop, so I need this to work when i=0.

```
for(int l = 0; l < L; l++){                     }
```

Comment: *Is there a concise way to exclude any row and/or column?*  -- Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Can probably be done with range views https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges . But the best would be for OP to describe their end goals

Comment: You can make just about anything concise by hiding the details in a function...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie fair point. I added more of an explanation as to why I want to accomplish this.

Comment: @Jeffrey I updated the post to describe my end goals. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You can try indirection.  Have another array denote the indices you want to process and loop over that array, i.e `array[index[i]]` instead of `array[i]`.  I wouldn't be surprised if that is how those other languages accomplish this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you please post an example as an answer so that I can see what you mean and accept it? Thank you!

Comment: Can you use some library for linear algebra? Like [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) - then you can just slice, invert, multiply etc.

Comment: As your other question is tagged `rcpparmadillo`, you may want to look at the *excellent* [Armadillo docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat). In particular, the link I give there is to the "submatrix views" topic. You can look at the `.submat()` method which essentially uses the indirection approach mentioned by @PaulMcKenzie  This is somewhat standard Armadillo fare

Comment: @duckmayr Thank you for your comment. I have added another update. I think I'm almost there, but if you could provide further help, that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: take a look over the lesser known [std::valarray](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems a more straightforward approach is to fill an `n-1` length `uvec` with sequential integers, just skipping `i`, like so:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat exclude_one_row_and_col(const arma::mat& X, arma::uword i) {
    arma::uword n = X.n_rows; // X should be square so only need # rows
    arma::uvec idx(n-1); // vector of indices to subset by
    arma::uword ii = 0; // the integer we'll add at each elem of idx
    for ( arma::uword j = 0; j < (n-1); ++j ) { // for each elem of idx
        if ( ii == i ) { // if ii equals i, we need to skip i
            ii += 1;     // (i.e., add 1 to ii)
        }
        idx[j] = ii;     // then we store ii for this elem
        ii += 1;         // and increment ii
    }
    return X.submat(idx, idx); // finally we can subset the matrix
}
```

A simple demonstration shows this works as expected:

```r
X <- diag(1:3)
X
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    2    0
# [3,]    0    0    3

exclude_one_row_and_col(X, 0)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    0
# [2,]    0    3

exclude_one_row_and_col(X, 1)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    0    3

exclude_one_row_and_col(X, 2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    0    2
```

Comment: This works excellent- thank you! Just one follow-up question: does the indexing in Rcpp:: functions work like C++ or R? 

Let me explain this a bit further. We know that R's indexing starts at 1 and C++ starts at 0. So, suppose that I want to invoke Rcpp::qnorm(p(i)) in Cpp. Well, i is starting at 0, so i is naturally one behind the correct index in R. When I call Rcpp::qnrom(p(i)), if I want to obtain the relatively correct value, should I instead call Rcpp::qnorm(p(i+1)) to correct for the shift in indexing? Or does Rcpp automatically correct for the shift in indexing?

Comment: @RonSnow Writing C++ using `Rcpp` or `RcppArmadillo` functions works just like any other C++, 0-indexing and all

Comment: So, it sounds like I don't need to shift the indices. Thanks for the clarification!